# jQuery - adding 2 insertAfter elements instead of 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, insertafter

I'm trying to `insertAfter` a span element when select another ID to hide other elements.

But the problem is when I have selected an `ID` once, it inserts a `span` element. Then when I select another ID, it should hide inserted span element, but it doesn't.

Later on, when I select again same ID, it `insertsAfter` another span element. That second element later works with the *hide code*, but first inserted element doesn't.

It adds #omniva double elemnt, and hides only one of it

[image]

```
<script>
$("#flat").click(function(){
  $("#show-lp24-select").hide();
  $("#show-omniva24-select").hide();
  $("#text-area-comment").show();
});

$("#lp24").click(function(){
  $("#text-area-comment").hide();
  $("#show-omniva24-select").hide();
  $("#show-lp24-select").insertAfter( $( "#lp24" ) ).show();
});

$("#button-shipping-method").click(function(){
  var selectBoxVal = $("#select-box-lp24").val();    //VALUE OF SELECT BOX
  $("#shipping-method-place").val("LP 24/7 terminalo adresas - "+selectBoxVal);   
});

$("#omniva").click(function(){
  $("#show-lp24-select").hide();
  $("#text-area-comment").hide();
  $("#show-omniva24-select").insertAfter( $( "#omniva" ) ).show();
});

$("#button-shipping-method").click(function(){
  var selectBoxVal = $("#select-box-omniva24").val();    //VALUE OF SELECT BOX
  $("#shipping-method-place").val("Omniva 24/7 terminalo adresas - "+selectBoxVal);   
});
</script>
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code in a [mcve]. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to provide a runnable example here on Stack Overflow. As it is, I don't see any use of the [`clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) function, which would actually clone the element. Also note that two elements in the DOM cannot share the same id attribute.

Answer (score 0):

**Three concepts below:**

1. Use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for your event handlers.
2. Use [delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) on dynamic stuff.
3. You can *coma-separate* the selectors in jQuery.

Have a close look at the ***voluntarly uncommented*** changes.
And if that fails...
Please have a look at the [console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers).

```
<script>
$(document).on("click","#flat",function(e){
  console.log("#"+e.target.id+" click!);
  $("#show-lp24-select, #show-omniva24-select").hide();
  $("#text-area-comment").show();
});

$(document).on("click","#lp24",function(e){
  console.log("#"+e.target.id+" click!);
  $("#text-area-comment, #show-omniva24-select").hide();
  $("#show-lp24-select").insertAfter( $( "#lp24" ) ).show();
});

$(document).on("click","#button-shipping-method",function(e){
  console.log("#"+e.target.id+" click!);
  var selectBoxVal = $("#select-box-lp24").val();    //VALUE OF SELECT BOX
  $("#shipping-method-place").val("LP 24/7 terminalo adresas - "+selectBoxVal);
});

$("document).on("click",#omniva",function(e){
  console.log("#"+e.target.id+" click!);
  $("#show-lp24-select, #text-area-comment").hide();
  $("#show-omniva24-select").insertAfter( $( "#omniva" ) ).show();
});

$(document).on("click","#button-shipping-method",function(e){
  console.log("#"+e.target.id+" click!);
  var selectBoxVal = $("#select-box-omniva24").val();    //VALUE OF SELECT BOX
  $("#shipping-method-place").val("Omniva 24/7 terminalo adresas - "+selectBoxVal);
});
</script>
```

> *«That second element later works...»*

...would translate into *"After a page refresh"* or *"days after"*... How would one know? ***;)***

Comment: Squarely replace your shown code with my suggestion and tell me if it *at least* does the same thing. ;)